# Javascript: How to get individual item ids when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript

When I click on the button it shows in the `console - undefined`

I have tried creating an event listener on click but it still does not work as expected,

**product_detail.html**

```
 {{course.title}}
 <li><button class="btn_adcart update-cart data-course={{course.id}}" data-action="add">Add to Cart</button></li>
```

**cart.js**

```
const updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (let i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++){
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        let productId = this.dataset.course
        let action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId', productId, 'action', action);
        
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `dataset` look like?

Comment: It looks like your quotation marks are not placed correctly around your class names, it is encompassing the `data-course` attribute

Comment: It should be `<li><button class="btn_adcart update-cart" data-course={{course.id}} data-action="add">Add to Cart</button></li>`

Comment: @GlenCarpenter Please make that an answer and/or vote to close as a typo

Comment: @GlenCarpenter your comment worked for me, i will make it an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the end quotation for the class name.

Wrong

```
class="btn_adcart update-cart data-course={{course.id}}"
```

Correct

```
class="btn_adcart update-cart" data-course={{course.id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your quotation marks are not placed correctly around your class names, it is encompassing the `data-course` attribute

It should be `<li><button class="btn_adcart update-cart" data-course={{course.id}} data-action="add">Add to Cart</button></li>`

***By: @GlenCarpenter***